# Importing data from access to excel using vba

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, import

I am trying to import data from the table "memory" in my access database called "Computer.accdb", which is located on the desktop to Excel. I was able to find a code online and it was able to run but it did not work properly. I added a reference to the ADO Object Library in Excel using Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 6.1 Library. Below is the following code:

```
Sub automateAccessADO_9()
'Using ADO to Import data from an Access Database Table to an Excel worksheet (your host application).
'refer Image 9a to view the existing SalesManager Table in MS Access file "SalesReport.accdb".

'To use ADO in your VBA project, you must add a reference to the ADO Object Library in Excel (your host application) by clicking Tools-References in VBE, and then choose an appropriate version of Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects x.x Library from the list.

'--------------
'DIM STATEMENTS

Dim strMyPath As String, strDBName As String, strDB As String, strSQL As String
Dim i As Long, n As Long, lFieldCount As Long
Dim rng As Range

'instantiate an ADO object using Dim with the New keyword:
Dim adoRecSet As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim connDB As New ADODB.Connection

'--------------
'THE CONNECTION OBJECT

strDBName = "Computer.accdb"
strMyPath = ThisWorkbook.Path
strDB = strMyPath & "\" & strDBName

'Connect to a data source:
'For pre - MS Access 2007, .mdb files (viz. MS Access 97 up to MS Access 2003), use the Jet provider: "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0". For Access 2007 (.accdb database) use the ACE Provider: "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0". The ACE Provider can be used for both the Access .mdb & .accdb files.
connDB.Open ConnectionString:="Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; data source=" & strDB

'--------------
'OPEN RECORDSET, ACCESS RECORDS AND FIELDS

Dim ws As Worksheet
'set the worksheet:
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

'Set the ADO Recordset object:
Set adoRecSet = New ADODB.Recordset

'Opening the table named SalesManager:
strTable = "memory"

'--------------
'COPY RECORDS FROM ALL FIELDS OF A RECORDSET:
'refer Image 9d to view records copied to Excel worksheet

adoRecSet.Open Source:=strTable, ActiveConnection:=connDB, CursorType:=adOpenStatic, LockType:=adLockOptimistic

Set rng = ws.Range("A1")
lFieldCount = adoRecSet.Fields.Count

For i = 0 To lFieldCount - 1
'copy column names in first row of the worksheet:
rng.Offset(0, i).Value = adoRecSet.Fields(i).Name
adoRecSet.MoveFirst

'copy record values starting from second row of the worksheet:
n = 1
Do While Not adoRecSet.EOF
rng.Offset(n, i).Value = adoRecSet.Fields(i).Value
adoRecSet.MoveNext
n = n + 1
Loop

Next i

'select column range to AutoFit column width:
Range(ws.Columns(1), ws.Columns(lFieldCount)).AutoFit
'worksheet columns are deleted because this code is only for demo:
Range(ws.Columns(1), ws.Columns(lFieldCount)).Delete
adoRecSet.Close

'close the objects
connDB.Close

'destroy the variables
Set adoRecSet = Nothing
Set connDB = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: *it did not work properly* is not a meaningful problem description. In what **specific way** did it *not work*?

Comment: If you just want to copy the whole table "memory" over to Excel, there is a much simpler way to do this using DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet. I don't see in your code why you couldn't just use that, but I might be missing something.

Comment: See whether you can use Excel's [Range.CopyFromRecordset Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839240.aspx)

Comment: It was able to run but all I saw was the first field of the access table being copied onto the cell(A1) and then it just disappears @Ken White

Comment: Sorry, I am new to all of this especially writing macros or coding on VBA, so I'm still in the process of learning this @hypetech

Comment: Is this a one time transfer or part of a routine? There's a button under the "External Data" Tab at the top to export to excel.

Comment: This would be part of a routine. For example, if I add more memory on the memory table in the access database, I would like for it to be updated in the excel file as well @hypetech

Comment: Thanks! I will check that method out when I get home @HansUp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want to do is transfer the table to excel, use

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet(acExport,, "memory", "file path of excel table")
```

Your code looks mostly useful if you want to change the data in some way while transferring it, but it doesn't look like you are doing that and therefore this is a much simpler way to run the same routine.

Comment: This only works if I use this code in access right? I am trying to import the access database file in excel but I want to be able to place them in certain cells. The code I copied above was just for me to see how it works. But thanks, this code will be useful for me as well. @hypetech

Comment: Yes you run this code in access. But it doesn't work if you want to place the data in certain cells, it just throws everything over into excel.

Comment: Gotcha, I need to be able to import the access file in excel. Thank you though, I will definitely use this code though for my other projects.