# How to append data from an excel file to an ODBC with Access VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, import

I'm trying to append records to an ODBC, but there is an error, here is the vba :

```
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("accesstable", dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)
i = wb.Sheets(1).Cells(wb.Sheets(1).Rows.Count, 1).End(-4162).Row
For n = 2 To i
    With rs
        .AddNew
            .Fields(0).Value = wb.Sheets(1).Cells(n, 1).Value
        .Update
    End With
    i = i + 1
Next n
```

And at the .Update line :

```
Run-time error '3155':
ODBC--insert on a linked table 'accesstable' failed
```

Do you know where this might come from please ?

Thank you.

Comment: It's not an ODBC connection but a linked Access table. Most likely, you are trying to insert some invalid value, so double-check your source data if they match the data type of the fields of the Access table.

Comment: Instead of Excel automation and looping cells, have you tried TransferSpreadsheet?

Comment: Also, the `dbSeeChanges` option is not required. It's only used when querying SQL server databases.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answers.
 @Gustav, I've tried to match de data type, so I modified the columns format on excel and then in VBA I forced it :
` 
            a = CStr(wb.Sheets(1).Cells(n, 1).Value)
            b = CDate(wb.Sheets(1).Cells(n, 2).Value)
            c = CDbl(wb.Sheets(1).Cells(n, 3).Value)
            d = CDbl(wb.Sheets(1).Cells(n, 4).Value)
            e = CDbl(wb.Sheets(1).Cells(n, 5).Value)
            f = CStr(wb.Sheets(1).Cells(n, 6).Value)
`
But I still have the same error. 
@June7 I will try it but I would prefer the loop I can add expections.

Comment: The only thing to do is to double-check your data. What and where we can't tell as we don't have your data.

Comment: Solved thanks, it was because there was a column that was not receiving the data as it updates automatically.

Answer (score 0):

you can use below ways:

```
Sub DAOCopyFromRecordSet(DBFullName As String, TableName As String, _
    FieldName As String, TargetRange As Range)
' Example: DAOCopyFromRecordSet "C:\FolderName\DataBaseName.mdb", _
    "TableName", "FieldName", Range("C1")
Dim db As Database, rs As Recordset
Dim intColIndex As Integer
    Set TargetRange = TargetRange.Cells(1, 1)
    Set db = OpenDatabase(DBFullName)
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(TableName, dbOpenTable) ' all records
    'Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM " & TableName & _
        " WHERE " & FieldName & _
        " = 'MyCriteria'", dbReadOnly) ' filter records
    ' write field names
    For intColIndex = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
        TargetRange.Offset(0, intColIndex).Value = rs.Fields(intColIndex).Name
    Next
    ' write recordset
    TargetRange.Offset(1, 0).CopyFromRecordset rs
    Set rs = Nothing
    db.Close
    Set db = Nothing
End Sub
```

[More info about above code](https://www.exceltip.com/import-and-export-in-vba/import-data-from-access-to-excel-dao-using-vba-in-microsoft-excel.html)
and you can find a good information in [Stack over flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30900305/importing-data-from-access-to-excel-using-vba)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but isn't it to paste records from access to an excel worksheet ?